# Best way to turn an integer into a month name in c#?

Tags: .net, parsing, date

Is there a best way to turn an integer into its month name in .net?

Obviously I can spin up a datetime  to string it and parse the month name out of there. That just seems like a gigantic waste of time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Month name from month number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184121/get-month-name-from-month-number)

Answer (score 275, accepted):

Try GetMonthName from DateTimeFormatInfo

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.getmonthname.aspx

You can do it by:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(1);
```

Comment: CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(1) as well

Answer (score 21):

Why not just use `somedatetime.ToString("MMMM")`?

Comment: So anytime I need to turn 1 into January, I need to new up a date time with an arbitrary year and day, in order to just get January?

Comment: That is correct, as a bonus, you can have it in any localizable language you want :)

Answer (score 20):

Updated with the correct namespace and object:

```
//This was wrong
//CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames[index];

//Correct but keep in mind CurrentInfo could be null
DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.MonthNames[index];
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  Nick Berardi provided the correct answer.

Comment: from now I will try to compile my answers first

Comment: Realizing this is an old question, I still want to point out that the accepted answer provided by Nick Berandi is more correct (at least for Microsoft's implementation - not sure about Mono), because the MonthNames property always clones the array of month names, making the whole thing a tad less efficient.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a static method from the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace:

```
string monthName = Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.MonthName(monthInt, false);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(year, month, day);
Response.Write(day + "-" + dt.ToString("MMMM") + "-" + year);
```

In this way, your month will be displayed by their name, not by integer.

Answer (score 2):

To get abbreviated month value, you can use `Enum.Parse();`

```
Enum.Parse(typeof(Month), "0");
```

This will produce "Jan" as result.

Remember this is zero-based index.