# How to get the month name in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime

How does one go about finding the month name in C#? I don't want to write a huge `switch` statement or `if` statement on the month `int`. In VB.Net you can use `MonthName()`, but what about C#?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to turn an integer into a month name in c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218908/best-way-to-turn-an-integer-into-a-month-name-in-c)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Month name from month number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184121/get-month-name-from-month-number)

Answer (score 186, accepted):

You can use the CultureInfo to get the month name. You can even get the short month name as well as other fun things.

I would suggestion you put these into extension methods, which will allow you to write less code later. However you can implement however you like.

Here is an example of how to do it using extension methods:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToMonthName());
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortMonthName());
        Console.Read();
    }
}

static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static string ToMonthName(this DateTime dateTime)
    {
        return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(dateTime.Month);
    }

    public static string ToShortMonthName(this DateTime dateTime)
    {
        return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(dateTime.Month);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Might I add that there is an `InvariantInfo` property that can be used as well. And, in my opinion, the following is a more simple/readable format for doing this: `DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(...)` or `DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(...)`

Answer (score 132):

Use the "MMMM" format specifier:

```
string month = dateTime.ToString("MMMM");
```

Comment: assuming you have a date. if not: `var month = new DateTime(1,i,1).ToString("MMMM");`

Answer (score 15):

```
string CurrentMonth = String.Format("{0:MMMM}", DateTime.Now)
```

Comment: You don't need the ToString().

Comment: Or String.Format, actually. Just DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM") is simpler.

Comment: I would have suggested that as well, but you already had that as another answer.  Gortok's method also demonstrates the use of placeholders to do the formatting, so I think it's a good alternative example.

Answer (score 9):

Supposing your date is today. Hope this helps you.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Today;

string thisMonth= dt.ToString("MMMM");

Console.WriteLine(thisMonth);
```

Answer (score 7):

If you just want to use MonthName then reference Microsoft.VisualBasic and it's in Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime

```
//eg. Get January
String monthName = Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.MonthName(1);
```

Answer (score -19):

```
    private string MonthName(int m)
    {
        string res;
        switch (m)
        {
            case 1:
                res="Ene";
                break;
            case 2:
                res = "Feb";
                break;
            case 3:
                res = "Mar";
                break;
            case 4:
                res = "Abr";
                break;
            case 5:
                res = "May";
                break;
            case 6:
                res = "Jun";
                break;
            case 7:
                res = "Jul";
                break;
            case 8:
                res = "Ago";
                break;
            case 9:
                res = "Sep";
                break;
            case 10:
                res = "Oct";
                break;
            case 11:
                res = "Nov";
                break;
            case 12:
                res = "Dic";
                break;
            default:
                res = "Nulo";
                break;
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: This does not answer the question of the OP, because they said: "I really do **not** want to write a huge switch statement [...]" (emphasis mine). Please read questions in detail before writing an answer.