# Get Month name from month number

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the MonthName in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975531/how-to-get-the-monthname-in-c)

I used the following c# syntax to get month name from month no but i get `August` i want only `Aug`..

```
System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo mfi = new 
System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo();
string strMonthName = mfi.GetMonthName(8).ToString();
```

Any suggestion...

Comment: Aside from .GetMonthName(int) not returning the string you're looking for, it *does* return a string, so the .ToString() is unnecessary

Comment: Wouldn't be easier just to add a .Substring(0,3)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the month name in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975531/how-to-get-the-month-name-in-c)

Answer (score 428, accepted):

For short month names use:

```
string monthName = new DateTime(2010, 8, 1)
    .ToString("MMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

For long/full month names for Spanish ("es") culture:

```
string fullMonthName = new DateTime(2015, i, 1).ToString("MMMM", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es"));
```

Comment: how would i use the code above if i want "August"? full month name?

Comment: @User6675636b20796f7521 `string monthName = new DateTime(2010, 8, 1)
    .ToString("MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: This: "string s = new DateTime(1958, month, 1).ToString("MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture());" gives me, "Non-invocable member 'System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture' cannot be used like a method."

Comment: B. Clay Shannon add ( ) around (new DateTime(1958, month, 1))

Comment: This answer is not the best IMHO to work from a month number instead of a DateTime like in OP question.  Lasse V. Karlsen answer's is more straightforward for short month name. And to get the month name in your local culture, use CultureInfo.CurrentCulture like in CharithJ answer's.

Comment: Can I use it without `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`?

Answer (score 351):

**For Abbreviated Month Names : "Aug"**

[DateTimeFormatInfo.GetAbbreviatedMonthName Method (Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.getabbreviatedmonthname(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Returns the culture-specific abbreviated name of the specified month
>   based on the culture associated with the current DateTimeFormatInfo
>   object.

```
string monthName = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(8)
```

**For Full Month Names : "August"**

[DateTimeFormatInfo.GetMonthName Method (Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.getmonthname.aspx)

> Returns the culture-specific full name of the specified month based on
>   the culture associated with the current DateTimeFormatInfo object.

```
string monthName = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(8);
```

Comment: GetMonthName return full month name. If you need it as JAN, FEB, etc.. you could use 
var month = 10; 
string monthName = new DateTime(2014, month, 1).ToString("MMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToUpper();

Comment: @DmitryPavlov `GetAbbreviatedMonthName()` is a better way to do that.

Comment: DateTimeFormatInfo should be DateTimeFormat (at least in .net 4.6)

Comment: Second option worked for me, although I used `GetCultureInfo("en-GB")` instead of `CurrentCulture` because I wanted to be sure, that my month name will always be in English

Answer (score 89):

Replace `GetMonthName` with [`GetAbbreviatedMonthName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.getabbreviatedmonthname.aspx) so that it reads:

```
string strMonthName = mfi.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(8);
```

Answer (score 18):

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(4)
```

This method return `April`

If you need some special language, you can add:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="es-ES" uiCulture="es-ES"></globalization>
     <compilation debug="true"
</system.web>
```

Or your preferred language.

For example, with `es-ES` culture:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(4)
```

Returns: `Abril`

Returns: `Abril` (in spanish, because, we configured the `culture as es-ES` in our `webconfig` file, else, you will get `April`)

That should work.

Answer (score 13):

You can get this in following way,

```
DateTimeFormatInfo mfi = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
string strMonthName = mfi.GetMonthName(8).ToString(); //August
```

Now, get first three characters

```
string shortMonthName = strMonthName.Substring(0, 3); //Aug
```

Comment: Nice, although you don't need to ToString() the call to GetMonthName(), as it already returns a string.

Answer (score 12):

You want `GetAbbreviatedMonthName`

Answer (score 8):

This should return month text *(January - December)* from the month index *(1-12)*

```
int monthNumber = 1; //1-12  
string monthName = new DateTimeFormatInfo().GetMonthName(monthNumber);
```

Comment: Please provide some additional information. Don't just post code

Answer (score 6):

You can also do this to get current Month :

```
string monthName = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(DateTime.Now.Month);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var month = 5;
var cultureSwe = "sv-SE";
var monthSwe = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureSwe).DateTimeFormat.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(month);
Console.WriteLine(monthSwe);

var cultureEn = "en-US";
var monthEn = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureEn).DateTimeFormat.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(month);
Console.WriteLine(monthEn);
```

Output

```
maj
may
```