# Iterate through Month name

Tags: c#

I have two Columns in Below format in my application (c#)

```
Month Name   Amount
Jan15   ==2000
Feb15 ==457
Mar15 =200
April15 =4666
May15 = 357
Jan16 = 332
feb16 =323
Mar16 =233
```

these columns are dynamic (any number of columns can cm in Same format)
I need to get the sum of all the amounts where month is after Mar15.
How to achieve that.
Pseudo code

```
If MonthName >Mar15
amount = sum (amount)
```

Comment: Why Jan15  is under month ?? Shouldn't it be Jan or January

Comment: When do you say that a given month is greater than `Mar15` ? Put that logic in a method and call it to check.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Month name from month number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184121/get-month-name-from-month-number)

Comment: Your data is way too inconsistent. Can't even parse the month as 3 letters because of April.

Comment: See the duplicate topic I suggest, split at fourth character and you'll be done. if you're data are ikconsistent (april) you'll have to do it manually and we won't write it for you so show your tries.

Comment: @KcDoD in My requirement it includes Year also with month

Comment: @AFract  Data will be always in below format...                                            Jan-14 Feb-14 Mar-14 Apr-14 May-14 Jun-14 Jul-14 Aug-14 Sep-14 Oct-14 Nov-14 Dec-14 Jan-15 Feb-15 Mar-15 Apr-15 May-15 Jun-15        how to compare Mar14 lesser value in this form of data

Comment: Then your sample is wrong. Read my answer again and try something.

Comment: @AFract duplicate link .,u hv provided convert from datetime format to MMM format ,,i need to convert from MMM format to datetime format to compare

Comment: Don't you think it's a little bit related ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `DateFormat` is always be going to like `Jan-14 Feb-14  Mar-14  Apr-14  May-14  Jun-14` then  you can try to use the `ParseExact` to convert it to the `DateTime` and then apply the `SUM` on it to get the result you want.

```
var result = dataList.Where(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x.monthName, "MMM-yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) > DateTime.ParseExact("Mar-15", "MMM-yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                     .Sum(x => x.Amount);
```

In above case it will give the `sum` of all amounts which has date greater than `Mar-15`.

---

**UPDATE**

To add the `Group BY` you can simply add as,

```
.GroupBy(x=>x.Id).Select(x=> new { Person = x.Key,TotalAmount = x.Sum(x=>x.Amount)})
```

Comment: Hey, If i need to add groupby column here then hw cn i add tat

Comment: How do you want to group By on which column ?

Comment: Actually in another method i hv one more column Id. Each Id is having these List of Month and amount value.  so i need sum of amount where month after Mar-15 for each ID.   Consider a scenario like a person spend some amount each month and like tat 50 person are there and i need to sum up for each person expenditure after March 15

Comment: Hi thanks for the help.. one more question,,if i need sum year wise..lik in the sample i need sum for 2014 separately and for 2015 separatly

Comment: Hi  In the another method i need sum for complete one year. in the above code its returning from Mar-15 to Dec 15 .. if i need sum from Mar-15 till Feb 16 and then Mar16 to Feb 17 n so on.. how to do that

Comment: Please ask it as separate question with test data and your tried code.