# Using a for loop when calling a method

Tags: c#

I'm using a for loop in a method to carry the result to the main function. I'm trying to use the for loop to get the month of a year and pass it on to the output from the main function.

I have nested an if loop in the for loop which I feel is probably redundant as the for loop will count to the end anyway.
It's probably a basic enough problem in the code but I have been staring at it for so long that I think it's burn out on my end.

The output is returning "Doesn't Exist" for all months instead of picking out the relevant month. How do I pick out the relevant month from the for loop or is that possible with the way I have coded so far?

```
namespace Month_Function_Call
    {
class Program
{
    public static String month_name(int month)
    {
        String result;
        result = "a";
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i )
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                result = "January";
            }
            if (i == 1)
            {
                result = "February";
            }
            if (i == 2)
            {
                result = "March";
            }
            if (i == 3)
            {
                result = "April";
            }
            if (i == 4)
            {
                result = "May";
            }
            if (i == 5)
            {
                result = "June";
            }
            if (i == 6)
            {
                result = "July";
            }
            if (i == 7)
            {
                result = "August";
            }
            if (i == 8)
            {
                result = "September";
            }
            if (i == 9)
            {
                result = "October";
            }
            if (i == 10)
            {
                result = "November";
            }
            if (i == 11)
            {
                result = "December";
            }
            else
            {
                result = "N/A";
            }


        }
            return result;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Month 1: " + month_name(1));
        Console.WriteLine("Month 2: " + month_name(2));
        Console.WriteLine("Month 3: " + month_name(3));
        Console.WriteLine("Month 4: " + month_name(4));
        Console.WriteLine("Month 5: " + month_name(5));
        Console.WriteLine("Month 6: " + month_name(6));
        Console.WriteLine("Month 7: " + month_name(7));
        Console.WriteLine("Month 8: " + month_name(8));
        Console.WriteLine("Month 9: " + month_name(9));
        Console.WriteLine("Month 10: " + month_name(10));
        Console.WriteLine("Month 11: " + month_name(11));
        Console.WriteLine("Month 12: " + month_name(12));
        Console.WriteLine("Month 43: " + month_name(43));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you looping instead of just comparing `month` in the `if` statements?

Comment: What problem are you encountering? What help are you actually seeking?  If its code review you are after then codereview.stackexchange.com exists and might be a better place for the question (but only if your code actually works).

Comment: You don't need a loop in your method, you need the loop in `Main` to pass month `1` to `12`. Also look into `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` so that you can get ride of the `if` statement in your method. Plus there are already methods available to get Month name based on number. One last thing is you need `if ... else ... if`  to sort out invalid choice, you may use `switch` here as well.

Comment: You compare against `0` for January, but start with `1` in your calling code.

Comment: You should also replace the entire, if...if... into a simple array lookup.
string []{"January", "February", ....}
Then, you can just look for the index you want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184121/get-month-name-from-month-number

Comment: @Damo, your main problem is you have a method accepting an `int` representing the month, but you never reference that object.  You method should use the information from its parameters in calculating a result.

Comment: Also you need to clarify if you want a zero based or one based indexing of the months.  In your  code `if (i == 0) { result = "January"; }` indicate you want a 0 based indexing, but then in your `Main` you run it for 1-12.

Comment: What a stomach ache!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make this cleaner by using `switch`

```
 switch (month)
        {
            case 0: return "January";
            case 1: return "February";
            case 2: return "March";
            case 3: return "April";
            case 4: return "May";
            case 5: return "June";
            case 6: return "July";
            case 7: return "August";
            case 8: return "September";
            case 9: return "October";
            case 10: return "November";
            case 11: return "December";
            default: return "N/A";
        }
```

Answer (score 7):

I think using `GetMonthName` from `DateTimeFormat` would be a better way of doing it. This will give you the name in the users active culture. (You can of course hard code this to any culture you like) Then `ToTitleCase` to get the first character as upper case.

```
public static String month_name(int month)
{
   if(month < 1 || month > 12) 
      return "N/A";
   var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
   var name = culture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(month);
   return culture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(name);
}
```

Comment: First the OP is using a zero based index for the month names and this uses a 1 based.  Second this returns an empty string for a value of 13 and  throws an exception for values less than 1 and greater than 13.

Comment: @juharr As for zero based index that seems to be wrong in his function if you look at his Main method it assumes 1 to be the first month.

Comment: @juharr you're right, that was a mistake I spotted after you mentioned it, took me a while to figure out why I got N\A for two months instead of one but it was the index that was wrong

Comment: @Magnus Yeah I just noticed that too and asked the OP to clarify

Answer (score 4):

Do something like this instead

```
string[] months = new string[12] {"January", "February", "March" }; // Input all months to this array

if (index <= -1 || index > 12) return "N/A";
return months[index];
```

Insert this code into the **getMonthName()** function

Comment: I saw your 43 test case, let me edit the answer that suits that, hmm.

Comment: Thank you that makes infinitely more sense than the nonsense I was typing! I knew it would be something simple that I missed

Comment: Just do `return index >= 0 && index < 12 ? months[index] : "N/A";`

Comment: @TuukkaX Yeah, I actually added that comment before you added the `if` though you current have the logic backwards.

Answer (score 3):

Dont use loop and if-else. What you need is dictionary.

```
static Dictionary<int, string> _monthName = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    {1,"January" }, // if zero based start from 0
    {2,"February" },
    {3,"March" },
    {4,"April" },
    {5,"May" },
    {6,"June" },
    {7,"July" },
    {8,"August" },
    {9,"September" },
    {10,"October" },
    {11,"November" },
    {12,"December" },
};

private static string GetMonthName(int i)
{
    var result = "";
    if (_monthName.TryGetValue(i, out result))
    {
        return result;
    }
    return "N/A";
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Month 1: " + GetMonthName(1));
    Console.WriteLine("Month 2: " + GetMonthName(2));
    Console.WriteLine("Month 3: " + GetMonthName(3));
    Console.WriteLine("Month 4: " + GetMonthName(4));
    Console.WriteLine("Month 5: " + GetMonthName(5));
    Console.WriteLine("Month 6: " + GetMonthName(6));
    Console.WriteLine("Month 7: " + GetMonthName(7));
    Console.WriteLine("Month 8: " + GetMonthName(8));
    Console.WriteLine("Month 9: " + GetMonthName(9));
    Console.WriteLine("Month 10: " + GetMonthName(10));
    Console.WriteLine("Month 11: " + GetMonthName(11));
    Console.WriteLine("Month 12: " + GetMonthName(12));
    Console.WriteLine("Month 43: " + GetMonthName(43));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion You should ommit using so many if statements in the for loop in this case because it is not readable enough and the better approach would be to create an array of type string which will have all the names of the months and to iterate this array. Your code would be like:

```
public static String month_name(int month) {
        String result;
        result = "a";
        // for the sake of readability I have split the line
        String[] allMonths = { 
                              "N/A", "January", "February", "March", "April",
                              "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", 
                              "October", "November", "December" 
                          };
        if (month >= 0 && month <= 12)
            result = allMonths[month];
        else
           result = "N/A";

        return result;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine("Month 1: " + month_name(1));
        Console.WriteLine("Month 2: " + month_name(2));
        Console.WriteLine("Month 3: " + month_name(3));
        Console.WriteLine("Month 4: " + month_name(4));
        Console.WriteLine("Month 5: " + month_name(5));
        Console.WriteLine("Month 6: " + month_name(6));
        Console.WriteLine("Month 7: " + month_name(7));
        Console.WriteLine("Month 8: " + month_name(8));
        Console.WriteLine("Month 9: " + month_name(9));
        Console.WriteLine("Month 10: " + month_name(10));
        Console.WriteLine("Month 11: " + month_name(11));
        Console.WriteLine("Month 12: " + month_name(12));
        Console.WriteLine("Month 43: " + month_name(43));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Hope it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the **Swith-Case** statement is the best choice here.

But, if you don't know how to use it, you should remove the **For**  statement, because it is completely non-sense.

```
 //for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i )
    //{

    //}
```