# How do I return the actual month name from a Date Entity using MVC Automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, automapper

I tried the following but it failed (as I expected it would) with "The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities."

```
string[] Months = new string[] 
{
    "JAN",
    "FEB",
    "MAR",
    "APR",
    "MAY",
    "JUN",
    "JUL",
    "AUG",
    "SEP",
    "OCT",
    "NOV",
    "DEC",
};

Mapper.CreateMap<DezReceiptModel, SelectablePaymentMonthYearViewModel>()
     .ForMember(dest => dest.DateOfServiceMonthCommaYear, 
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Months[src.DateOfService.Month].ToString() + src.DateOfService.Year.ToString()));
```

Comment: Instead of having your custom Months array, you could use the builtin one. Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184121/get-month-name-from-month-number

Comment: The `Map` method should work. From the exception looks like you are using `ProjectTo`. Please clarify your question.

Comment: @Mohammed Akbari Please show me how you would use your suggestion in my original code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the date column is not null. You can refer my solution:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<DezReceiptModel, SelectablePaymentMonthYearViewModel>()
             .ForMember(dest => dest.DateOfServiceMonthCommaYear, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.DateOfService.ToString("MMM").ToUpper() + "-" + src.DateOfService.Year.ToString()));
```

Comment: This will not work because LINQ will not be able to translate .Tostring("MMM") to SQL. It is strange that it will translate .Tostring() but adding formatting will cause an exception. That was actually on of the first things I tried.