# Get date in correct language

Tags: c#, xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I've added a label with the date in days and the month in letters but I need it to show the right language also.

I've got this label:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{0:dd MMMM}'}"></Label>
```

I've got this in the ViewModel:

```
public class EventPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;
    //public DelegateCommand Date { get; set; }

    public EventPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
    }

    DateTime _startdate;
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get
        {
            return _startdate;
        }
        set
        {
            _startdate = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Date");

        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried lots of things but how can i somehow add this:

```
CultureInfo MyCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("se-SE");
```

So that is say October in my desired language instead.

Thanks alot!!

Comment: it should automatically use the language/locale settings of the device

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184121/get-month-name-from-month-number) answer.

Answer (score 0):

You did not say if you are using `resx/resw`-based localization or OS native....

#### Setting the default thread culture:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("se-SE");
```

#### Setting the culture at the individual thread level..

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("se-SE");
```

#### Setting it via Xamarin.Forms localization:

[Globalizing Xamarin.Forms Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/text?tabs=windows)

You can set the culture at the Forms level

```
AppResources.Culture =  new CultureInfo("se-SE");
```