# How to fill comboboxes with days, months and years?

Tags: c#

I have 3 comboboxes. `1st: days`,`2nd: months`,`3rd: years`.
I would like to fill the combobox with the correct days, i think leap year...

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
{
comboBoxDays.Items.Add(i);
} 

for (int i = DateTime.Now.Year; i <= 2050; i++)
{
 comboBox1Month.Items.Add(i);
}
```

How I fill the days with correct numbers? If the year is a leap year.

Comment: wpf or winforms?

Comment: You will need to react on change of the combobox. Either with Javascript or add a Listener. Depending on your stack.

Comment: It is a winform.

Comment: Why not to use `DateTimePicker`?

Comment: What exactly is the issue?  What is your question?  Are you asking how many days are in a month?  How to determine if a given year is a leap year?  Something else?  What have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: Your code already generates a list of numbers, so it's easy to change this to generate days 1-31, and years now-2050. To generate the month names, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184121/get-month-name-from-month-number

Comment: I can't use DateTimePicker because, the combobox i will use to a search. If i choosed the year, the month and day is null, a datagridview show from the database all data where year = 2019 etc.

Comment: I will recommend using builf in componnent like `DateTimePicker`  or `MonthCalendar`. Don't try to handle leap years years an number of day in month when [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.7.2) already support it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [DateTime.DaysInMonth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.daysinmonth?view=netframework-4.7.2) method that gives you the number of days in a particular month, even for leap years.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int year = 2019;
int month = 4;

int[] days = Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month)).ToArray();
int[] years = Enumerable.Range(DateTime.Now.Year, 2050).ToArray();
string[] months = new string[]{"Jan","Feb","Mar","..."};

comboBoxDays.DataSource = days;
comboBoxDays.DataBind();

comboBoxYears.DataSource = years;
comboBoxYears.DataBind();

comboBox1Month.DataSource = months;
comboBox1Month.DataBind();
```