# Having trouble with code to convert number into a month

Tags: c#, if-statement

here is my source code, everything is good until i get to the output and I cant get this to work.  Visual Studio doesn't like what I have in the output section, labeled //OUTPUT.

What do I need to add or change to get this to work?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int monthNumber;
    string monthName;

    //INPUT
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of the month");
    monthNumber = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

    //PROCCESSESS
    if (monthNumber == 1)
    {
        monthName = "January";
    }
    else if (monthNumber == 2)
    {
        monthName = "February";
    }
    else if (monthNumber == 3)
    {
        monthName = "March";
    }
    else if (monthNumber == 4)
    {
        monthName = "April";
    } 
    else if (monthNumber == 5)
    {
        monthName = "May";
    }
    else if (monthNumber == 6)
    {
        monthName = "June";
    }
    else if (monthNumber == 7)
    {
        monthName = "July";
    }
    else if (monthNumber == 8)
    {
        monthName = "August";
    }
    else if (monthNumber == 9)
    {
        monthName = "September";
    }
    else if (monthNumber == 10)
    {
        monthName = "October";
    } 
    else if (monthNumber == 11)
    {
        monthName = "November";
    }
    else if (monthNumber == 12)
    {
        monthName = "December";
    }

    //space to increase readability
    Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);

    //OUTPUT
    Console.WriteLine("Month:" + monthName);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: "Visual Studio doesn't like what I have" means what?

Comment: where you getting problem? and what is that?

Comment: in //output I get a unassigned variable but its assigned

Comment: initialize those variable something like this `int monthNumber = 0; and string monthName = string.Empty;` (int is optional).

Comment: A better way to get Month Name from the number: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/975531/how-to-get-the-monthname-in-c

Comment: Using that many if statements isn't a good coding style.
Using some kind of mapping, perhaps a dictionary whose key is the int number and string display name.

So your code endsup looking like this

string name = mapping[monthId];

Comment: Another alternative is a switch-statement.

Comment: @Boas Enkler, this is a class assignment, the professor wanted us to do it like this so we can grasp the concept of the if else statments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`monthName` must be initialized before use. So you can change the declaration line as

```
string monthName = null;
```

That's because the code does not guarantee that `monthName` gets assigned. For example what if the input number is 13?

Answer (score 4):

You have a lot of `else if`, but in the end, there's no `else` to cover the case where none of the `if` apply. Therefore the compiler can't guarantee that `monthName` was ever assigned. Maybe the user typed `"28"`?

It would look better to use a `switch` statement with twelve `case` sections and one `default` section.

But also, the month names are built into the framework. So with `using System.Globalization;` you could simply say

```
monthName = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(monthNumber);
```

or

```
monthName = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(monthNumber);
```

You can also get a `DateTime` directly from the input:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(Console.ReadLine(), "%M", null);
```

Then

```
monthName = dateTime.ToString("MMMM");
```

Answer (score 0):

- a) declare a variable
- b) if you are using month names, and you want some specific names, try using enum. really eazy and functional.

You can make your own setup of names/markings with your own pace of numbering those names/markings.

For Eg.

> enum Days {Sat=1, Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri};