# currently selected month in asp.net calendar control

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I know which month is selected when no date is selected.

For eg, on page load, the calendar will show december. The user click ">" button to show January.

How do I know that he has selected January?

Tkz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `VisibleMonthChanged` event to identify that.

```
protected void Cal1_VisibleMonthChanged(object sender, MonthChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //e.NewDate.Month will have the new visible month
}
```

To obtain the name of the month, check these web pages.

[Best way to turn an integer into a month name in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218908/best-way-to-turn-an-integer-into-a-month-name-in-c)

http://www.norecursion.com/blog/archive/2010/05/21/how-to-get-month-name-from-integer.aspx