# How do I get only unique month and year combinations?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Using VBNET, MVC 3 and Entity Framework to write my first mvc application - a single user blog application. I am trying to create an archive sidebar that will render something like October 2011 and when the user clicks they will see all posts in october. Right now all my attempts show either duplicate dates - if there are 3 posts in october then i see october 2011 3 times or i only get back one month year combo say oct 2011.

Using groupby with firstordefault i only get back one month yaear combo.

```
posts = _rdsqlconn.Posts.Where(Function(p) p.PostIsPublished = True).GroupBy(Function(d) d.PostDatePublished).FirstOrDefault
```

How can i get back unique month year combos with EF?

---

**Additional info**

I have that function in my repository. I want to pull the month and year pairs so that i have only one pair for say ocotober even if there are 3 posts in october. 
In the repository:

```
Public Function SelectPostsByDate() As IEnumerable(Of Entities.Post) Implements Interfaces.IPostRepository.SelectPostsByDate  

 Using _rdsqlconn As New RDSQLConn
            Dim posts
            posts = _rdsqlconn.Posts.Where(Function(p) p.PostIsPublished = True).GroupBy(Function(p) New With {p.PostDateCreated.Year, p.PostDateCreated.Month}).Select(Function(g) g.Key)
            'posts = _rdsqlconn.Posts.Where(Function(p) p.PostIsPublished = True).GroupBy(Function(p) New With {p.PostDatePublished.Value.Year, p.PostDatePublished.Value.Month})
            Return posts
        End Using
    End Function
```

In my controller i have

```
  Function DateViewPartial() As PartialViewResult
        Return PartialView(_postRepository.SelectPostsByDate)
    End Function
```

My partial view has:

```
      @ModelType IEnumerable (of RiderDesignMvcBlog.Core.Entities.Post)
    <hr />
    <ul style="list-style: none; margin-left:-35px;"> 
   @For Each item In Model       
      @<li> @Html.ActionLink(item.PostDatePublished.Value.ToString("Y"), "Archives", "Blog", New With {.year = item.PostDatePublished.Value.Year, .month = item.PostDatePublished.Value.Month}, Nothing)</li>      
     Next
     </ul>
```

In _Layout.vbhtml i call the partial view to render in the sidebar:

```
 <h3>Posts by Date</h3>
        @code
            Html.RenderAction("DateViewPartial", "Blog")
        End Code
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try this (in C#):

```cs
var yearMonths = _rdsqlconn.Posts
    .Where(p => p.PostIsPublished)
    .GroupBy(p => new { p.PostDatePublished.Year, p.PostDatePublished.Month })
    .Select(a => a.Key)
    .ToList();
```

It gives you a list of anonymous objects. Each object has a `Year` and a `Month` property - for instance `yearMonths[0].Year` and `yearMonths[0].Month`, etc. By applying the `Select` you actually throw away the elements in each group and you get only a list of group keys (year and month).

**Edit**

I think, for your purpose the best way is to introduce a "ViewModel" for your sidebar partial view. The `ViewModel` would describe the year and month group, for instance:

```cs
public class ArchiveMonthViewModel
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
}
```

Then you don't group with an anonymous type but use this ViewModel type:

```cs
var archiveViewModels = _rdsqlconn.Posts
    .Where(p => p.PostIsPublished)
    .GroupBy(p => new ArchiveMonthViewModel
    {
        Year = p.PostDatePublished.Year,
        Month = p.PostDatePublished.Month
    })
    .Select(a => a.Key)
    .ToList();
```

`archiveViewModels` is now a named type: `List<ArchiveMonthViewModel>` which you can return from your method:

```cs
public IEnumerable<ArchiveMonthViewModel> SelectPostsByDate()
{
    // code above ...
    return archiveViewModels;
}
```

Now your partial view should be based on a model of type `IEnumerable<ArchiveMonthViewModel>` (and not `IEnumerable<Post>`). In your foreach loop (`@For Each item In Model`) you pull out the `ArchiveMonthViewModel` elements which are the `item` in the loop now and then create the action link using `item.Year` and `item.Month`.

(Hopefully you can translate this sketch into VB.)

Comment: Can you post the equivalent vbnet expression. I am having trouble converting it to vbnet

Comment: @Ashok: Me too :) I think Jim Wooley already posted the VB translation in his answer here.

Comment: OK that works - i get just one month and year for october. Since i am now dealing with month and year as int, is there an easy way to convert the month number to month name?

Comment: @Ashok: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218908/best-way-to-turn-an-integer-into-a-month-name-in-c

Answer (score 0):

In VB:

```
Dim groupedPosts = _rdsqlcon.Posts.
        Where(Function(p) p.PostIsPublished = True).
        GroupBy(Function(p) New With {p.PostDatePublished.Year, p.PostDatePublished.Month }).
        Select(g => g.Key)
```

This just returns the unique Years and Months. If you want to include the Posts for each, try the following:

```
Dim groupedPosts = _rdsqlcon.Posts.
            Where(Function(p) p.PostIsPublished = True).
            GroupBy(Function(p) New With {p.PostDatePublished.Year, p.PostDatePublished.Month
```

From there, you can show the year/month groupings and the associated posts for each:

```
For Each group In groupedPosts
   Console.WriteLine(group.Key.Year & "-" & group.Key.Month)
   For Each post In group
      Console.WriteLine(post.PostDatePublished)
   Next
Next
```

Comment: Now it throws - Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[VB$AnonymousType_0`2[System.Int32,System.Int32]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[RiderDesignMvcBlog.Core.Entities.Post]'.

Comment: I am still getting this anonymous type error message. `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[VB$AnonymousType_0`2[System.Int32,System.Int32]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[RiderDesignMvcBlog.Core.Entities.Post]'.`

Comment: @Ashok: It's impossible that you get this error with the code above. What are you really doing? Are you using an existing variable `posts` which is an `IEnumerable<Post>` instead of creating a new instance with the query? `Dim posts` is important! You cannot declare a typed variable up front because the resulting type is anonymous.

Comment: @Slauma, here is the entire function: `Public Function SelectPostsByDate() As IEnumerable(Of Post) Implements IPostRepository.SelectPostsByDate

            Using _rdsqlconn As New RDSQLConn
                Dim posts
                posts = _rdsqlconn.Posts.Where(Function(p) p.PostIsPublished = True).GroupBy(Function(p) New With {p.PostDateCreated.Year, p.PostDateCreated.Month}).Select(Function(g) g.Key)
                Return posts
            End Using
        End Function`

Comment: @Ashok: Problem is that you try to return an anonymous type collection from a method - which is not possible and causes your error. What is your method exactly supposed to return? I thought you wanted a collection of group keys (year/month) or groups. What is the collection of posts you want to return? You can edit your question and explain it there, it's hard to read here in the comments.